# Replace first opening parentheses and number with new number

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I am using Visual Studio/C# and have the following string:

```
string test = "We have files (15 files)";
```

Now I want to replace the first number (integer) after the first opening parentheses.

For example if we replace 15 with a 6, the string would now have this value:

```
"We have files (6 files)"
```

This is what I have so far but it's not working:

```
int newCount = 6;
test = Regex.Replace(test, "([0-9]", "(" + newCount );
```

Thanks in advance

**NOTE #1:**
I would need to check for an opening parentheses in case there are numbers in the first area. For example below:

```
"There are 20 missing (400 processed)"
```

If passing 450, the result would be:

```
"There are 20 missing (450 processed)"
```

Comment: have you considered using string interpolation instead (i.e. like `string test = $"We have files ({newCount} files)";`)? Or do you have to use / work on an existing string?

Comment: Thank you bassfader.  Yes I have to use an existing string.

Comment: regex might be overkill for that task. Usual method with `indexOf` faster and might be enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because of two things.

First: `(` is a character used by RegEx, to match it literally you need to escape it with an `\`: `\(`

Second: You only match one Number, so when you'd try to match `(15` it would only match and replace `(1`

```
int newCount = 6;
test = Regex.Replace(test, @"\(\d+", "(" + newCount );
```

This should do the trick! Check out the Explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/cIlXwO/1)

**EDIT**

A better way would be to only match the number:

```
test = Regex.Replace(test, @"\d+", newCount.ToString());
```

Comment: So, why must use `(` in there?

Comment: @TânNguyễn it doesn't have to, i just answered what he asked for, using his example.

Comment: BoredomOverload, good work.  I would need to check for parenthes in case there is another numbers in the first area.  I am receiving an error in Visual Studio regarding the escape sequences on your first example.

Comment: @RobertSmith Sorry, you need to escape the pattern string with an `@` because it now contains a `\\`. I updated my answer!

Comment: the edit answer isnt good, you will get `There are 450 missing (450 processed)`

Comment: @styx the Note OP added was added after i made my Edit. Now it's of course not the better way :)

Comment: Thank you gentlemen.  I am using the first answer provided by BoredomOverload and it works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string test = "We have files (15 files)";
string pattern = "\d+";
string replacement = "6";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(test, replacement);
```

You dont need to replace the bracket. The above regex only selects the number, which can be any number of digits long.

Comment: Thanks Nick good job.  I would need to check for an opening parentheses in case there are numbers in the first area.  Sorry I didn't mention that.

Answer (score 0):

```
  int newCount = 6;
  string test = "We have files (15 files)";
  test = Regex.Replace(test, @"\([0-9]+", newCount.ToString());
```

I tried to do the least amount of changes

you are missing the "+" operator which  basically says "one or more"

and after your **Edit** you are also missing "\"  which escape a special character

you can always mess around with regex online and check your pattern [here](https://regexr.com/)

**Edit:**

`test = Regex.Replace(test, "[(0-9]", "(" + newCount);` won't work because you will you replace the *first* encounter of every pattern and you will get: `We have files (6(6(6 files)` because it matches `"(", "1", "5"` and if the original text was  `We have files (156 files)` [added 6 at the end] you will get  `We have files (6(6(6(6 files)` because not it matches "(" ,"1", "5", "6"